# Using rapidjson::Document as pointer error

Tags: c++, document, rapidjson

I have a class variable that is a pointer, rapidjson::Document. I'm having trouble using this pointer with ParseStream.  I can't find any examples of using a pointer for the document variable.  Maybe someone else has luck using this as a pointer instead of a reference?  I'm having trouble with the compilation error/seeing what's the issue.

```
OurClassDOM.h
class OurClassDOM {
   OurClassDOM(){}

   template<typename T> OurClassDOM(const OurString &n, const T &v)
   :
   pDocument(new rapidjson::Document(n, v)){}

   OurClassDOM(const OurClassDOM &rhs)
   {
      pDocument = new rapidjson::Document;
      //copy it
   }

   OurClassDOM(const rapidjson::Document &rhs)
   {
      pDocument = new rapidjson::Document;
      //copy it
   }

   virtual OurClassDOM clone() const
   {return(*this); }

private:
OurClassDOM &operator=(const OurClassDOM &);
ourPtr<rapidjson::Document> pDocument;
...
}

OurclassDOM.cpp
    ...
 void OurClassDOM::parse(const std::string& json) const {
    rapidjson::StringStream strString(json.c_str());
    pDocument->ParseStream(strStream); 
 }
 ...
//compilation error at -> says: 
error C2662: 'rapidjson::GenericDocument<Encoding> &rapidjson::GenericDocument<Encoding>::ParseStream<0,rapidjson::StringStream>(InputStream &)' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const rapidjson::Document' to 'rapidjson::GenericDocument<Encoding> &'
```

I can only get this to compile when it's like this:

```
rapidjson::Document document;
rapidjson::StringStream strStream(json.c_str());
rapidjson::ParseResult result = document.ParseStream(strStream); //compiles
```

How do I get it to compile with the pointer?  I already have the pointer throughout my constructors, etc. and would prefer not to switch to a class reference. I can't find any examples online of using a pointer document with this instead of a reference.

Comment: Looks like you trying to call nonconst function through the pointer to const class instance. Show more of your code.

Comment: @user2807083 - See code added

Comment: I figured it out.  I had const at the end of the parse method.  That means Iican't change member variables in it.

Comment: You can either remove `const` modifier out of your `parse()` function, or add `mutable` modifier to your `pDocument` member. The last is not so "clean" as first.